# My authorize function is always failing in laravel-5.8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-middleware, laravel-authorization

I created one policy inside create function i am checking weather this user can able to create records and i am registering the Model and policy in the `AthServiceProvider.php` after that i am checking inside the controller by using `$this->authorize('create')` it's failing always even the user is valid,can you please help me how to resolve this issue

`Error:- This Action is unathorized`

`restaurentContoller.php`

```
class RestaurentsController extends Controller
{
    protected $repository;

    public function __construct(RestaurentRepository $repository){
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function postRestaurent(RestaurentRequest $request){
        $data = $request->all();
        $data['admin_id'] = $this->getAccountId($request);
        $this->authorize('create');
        $rest = $this->repository->create($data);
        return response()->json(fractal($rest,new RestuarentTransformer));        
    }
}
```

`RestaurentPolicy.php`

```
   public function create(User $user)
    {
        return ($user->admin_id=1) ? true : false;
    }
```

`api.php`

```
Route::post('/postRest',[RestaurentsController::class,'postRestaurent'])->middleware(['CheckAdmin']);
```

Comment: Are you using Request Classes?

Comment: Yes i am using request class

Answer (score 0):

If you use Request Classes you have to change authorize method return false to true

```
class RestaurentStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```